# Advantage to using SSRS or Crystal reports when the output is simple and static?

Tags: sql, asp.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I have an ASP.NET/C# web app in which the user needs to run reports with various criteria that will ALWAYS yield simple, 2-dimensional, tabular data. I'm tempted to use a sophisticated reporting engine like SSRS or Crystal Reports, but these seem like overkill, since there's really nothing to **design** (all outputs will be to CSV, or JSON for the browser to render in an HTML table).

In this scenario, am I eating too much complexity by trying to use SSRS or Crystal Reports?  Should I instead just write custom classes to dynamically assemble SQL statements (based on user selections) that will be fired against the database?

Does SSRS or CR add anything that is of value (within the requirements constraints I've already described)...?

Answer (score 0):

Its depend on your requirement if you want to minimal overhead on your web app then please go ahead and use your custom codes since you are not required any styling or extra functions.

Just get JSON objects and fill in HTML and go Head !!

Answer (score 0):

I am working with ssrs So i will talk just about it:

- ssrs is a very useful tool for building a Reports

all You need is sql server Stored Procedure to build your report

then deploy it to report server and use this report from your app

-now all you need in your app just one page for all reports and you path the URL

dynamically with report name

- ---
- You need to know this :

-ssrs did not work correctly with all browser

for Exp : 
-Print Btn just work with IE

so Mozila and Google you need to use java script to print Report

-some issue with criteria section :

there is no way to  rename the 'select value' with drop down

so you need to use java scrip to handle it

also you find ( Null and chick box )  any customer did not know what null mean so

you need first to remove null keyword or to rename it to anther Keyword

also you need java script to  do this

---

the most problem i have :

all reports in reports server so 
when i go to a new client what i need

just Sql server no need to setup visual studio and ssrs tool

just to deploy all reports on client report server

its very bad ..

i solved this issue with tool i had make to deploy the all the report

and no need to setup  VS just to deploy the report

---

i think that the most important problem i have

and all of it i found a work around to solve .. and it takes more time

finally : 
use ssrs or CR its very easy to use and make report very fast no need to create a custom page for report and develop all its control just like print and export

report to PDF,excel or any type

but if you have a few report i think no need to use any reports tool